# почему падает slimerjs при wait?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть в коде такая рекурсия

```
recursiveOpenPage() {
    //sl.setNumber(sl.getNumber() + 1);
    console.log('current page - ' + sl.getNumber());
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('start wait');
            slimer.wait(5000);
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('end wait');
            return sl.getImages();
        })
        .then((images) => {
            images.forEach(function(imageObj, index, array){
                page.clipRect = imageObj;
                page.render(sl.getPath() + 'images/' + sl.getNumber() + '.png')
            });
            return true;
        })
        .then(() => {
            sl.setNumber(sl.getNumber() + 1);
            return true;
        })
        // next page
        .then(() => {
            if(sl.getNumber() <= sl.getCount()) {
                let selector = '.top-block .nextButton';
                sl.clickSelector(page, selector);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(sl.getNumber());
            console.log(sl.getCount());
            if(sl.getNumber() <= sl.getCount()) {
                return sl.recursiveOpenPage();
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('resolve');
        });
}
```

так вот, когда загружается новая страница, то данный код не всегда отрабатывает. Иногда он подвисает вот в этом моменте `slimer.wait(5000);` В чем может быть причина?

Comment: что за slimer и slimerjs? что делает функция `wait`?

Comment: где вызывается _recursiveOpenPage_?